# Massless representation of $so(3,2)$

Tags: angular-momentum, field-theory, quantum-spin, group-theory, representation-theory

I am studying the article by Flato and Fronsdahl (http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF00400170). And they say that in the massless case, if the spin $s$ = 0, then the representation $D(1.0)$ (formula (3)) is given as follows:
$$D(1,0): E=J+1, J+3, \dots$$

I do not understand why there is no $E=2, J=0$. I tried to define a vector with the highest weight with such values, but I could not show that it should be absent. Why is there no such state?

Comment: can you add details?  I presume $J$ refers to SO(3) irreps but what is $E$?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero representations of $so(3, 2)$ decompose into representations of $so(2)\bigoplus so(3)$, each of them labelled by $so(2)$ and $so(3)$
weights, $E$ and $J$, as I understand it